# How to remove li elements when on click?

Tags: javascript, html

If there are a many `li` elements, I wanta product catalogue some as shops have.
`Html`:

```
<p> Choose collor: <span class="Black">Black</span>, <span class="white ">white </span>, <span class="Yellow">Yellow </span>

<ul>
  <li id="Black"> Black Shoe </li>
  <li id="white"> white Shoe </li>
  <li id="Yellow "> Yellow Shoe </li>
</ul>
```

And i want to remove other element withoud this one, that i clicked:

```
var Black = document.getElementById("Black");
var white = document.getElementById("white");
var Yellow = document.getElementById("Yellow ");


document.getElementsByClassName("Black").onclick = function() { white.style.display = 'none';
Yellow.style.display = 'none'; };

document.getElementsByClassName("white").onclick = function() { Black.style.display = 'none';
Yellow.style.display = 'none'; };

document.getElementsByClassName("Yellow").onclick = function() { white.style.display = 'none';
Black.style.display = 'none'; };
```

But the problem is when maybe user click on Black it hides white and yellow, but when afterfards user click on yellow, yellow is already hidden.

How can I restore?

Also i mean how to configure it correctly?

When i click black it must hide white adn yellow and after that when i click on white it should show white that was hided from last function.

Comment: If you hide other elements on click, how can a user click on them later?. Just add an `active` class on the selected item and show it highlighted. That's it!

Comment: So are you attempting to have a filtering list? i.e. like Amazon where theres a sidebar, where I can select color, material, price, etc. and it filters down the product list shown to me based on my selections?

Answer (score 0):

you can use different functions for all li elements 
first when you click on black li the function should run and hide the alternative li's 
also make a function and call it on keyup event when you keyup or on mouseout the function will show the recommended li's and that all do it for all the other li's still have confusion you can ask in reply :)

Answer (score 0):

you can assign a specific class by adding

```
$( this ).toggleClass( "new_class_name")
```

and use css to hide this .new_class_name

[check the source](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

---

> However  since you are ***not*** using jquery then you should do
>   something like

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
   var elemenBlackt = document.getElementById("Black");
   elementBlack.classList.toggle("new_class_name");
}
</script>
```

check the example [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_toggle_class)

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You could hide all li elements and then reveal the one you want. Something like this:

```
<ul>
  <li class="color" id="Black"> Black Shoe </li>
  <li class="color" id="white"> white Shoe </li>
  <li class="color" id="Yellow "> Yellow Shoe </li>
</ul>


var reveal = function(idName) {
  document.getElementById(idName).style.display = 'inline-block';
}

var hideAllButOne = function(idName) {
  document.getElementsByClassName("color").style.display = 'none';
  reveal(idName); 
}

document.getElementsByClassName("Black").onclick = function() { hideAllButOne('Black') };

document.getElementsByClassName("white").onclick = function() { hideAllButOne("white")  };

document.getElementsByClassName("Yellow").onclick = function() { hideAllButOne("Yellow")  };
```